# 'dotnet xunit' not working in Linux on a fresh xUnit project

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, xunit

I created a fresh xUnit project, with just a very simple (passing) test.

I have the latest version of everything, on my machine, but being a developer, I have also many previous versions.

If I run locally 'dotnet xunit' I get the (now probably famous):

```
    The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0'.
```

I can solve this problem, again, locally, with this call (available everywhere googling around):

```
dotnet xunit --fx-version 2.0.3
```

And it's all ok.

Now I go to a Linux virtual machine, that acts as an agent for a Jenkins build process, where neither of these calls work.
I suspect that this is because being a fresh virtual machine, I only installed the *latest* version of the SDK, so it cannot find the 'fallback' version 2.0.3, or something like this.
What can I do, in such a case?
Thanks in advance.

NOTE: The installed version of the .net core sdk in the linux machine is 2.1.101, and if I try

```
dotnet xunit --fx-version 2.1.101
```

I obtain the same error message above, but of course with 2.1.101 instead of 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass framework version into `--fx-version`, not the SDK. You can find where `dotnet` is installed from `dotnet --info` and then list all framework versions

```
$ dotnet --info | grep 'Base Path'
Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.4/

$ ls /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/
1.0.3  1.0.4  1.0.5  1.1.1  1.1.2  2.0.0  2.0.3  2.0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we solved installing version 2.0.3, and explicitly setting that in --fx-version.